# Function returning null and then print the data

Tags: flutter

Hey i am new to flutterand my function is returning null and after that the variable data get printed... i also added async and await but still facing the same issue.. any type of help will greatly appreciated..

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

const kAndroidUserAgent =
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36';


class mainController{
  Future getdata() async{
    String data;

    final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

    flutterWebViewPlugin.launch('https://www.instagram.com/picsart/?__a=1', hidden: true, userAgent: kAndroidUserAgent,);


    flutterWebViewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((viewState) async {
      if (viewState.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
        data = await flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript("document.documentElement.outerText");

        print(data); //after returning null it gets printed
        
        flutterWebViewPlugin.close();
      }
    });

    return data;
  }
}
```

OUTPUT
[Ouput image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/434B5.png)

Comment: it is because async is not gonna help you also need to add await when you are killing for response. look for code where you need to use await for network call.

Comment: @Kudos can you please tell me where to add await bz i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

try this
use if statement like that

```
if(data.hasdata){
//do something ;
}else{
CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

I hope its work..